# How do I access env.IsDevelopment() from a Blazor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'd like to use `env.IsDevelopment()` to control what content I see on a Blazor page.

I could add a singleton to the `Startup` class:

```
public static IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; private set; }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    Env = env;
}
```

Or is there another way to access `IWebHostEnvironment` (or `Startup`) via an instance variable?

Comment: You can inject `IWebHostEnvironment` via Startup constructor so that it is available before `ConfigureServices`. Should be able to add it to service collection from there and inject it into the view

Comment: If that fails create your own service to hold the desired information and have that injected where needed.

Comment: Okay. Mind blown - didn't realise that `Startup` was using injection!

Comment: Check docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Turns out that I can do this with injection. I added the following on my page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Env
```

Which allowed me to do stuff like this:

```
@if ( Env.IsDevelopment() )
{
    <div>Some content that I'm testing and don't want on the server yet</div>
}
```

Thanks @Nkosi!

Comment: Spot on - perfect for me

Comment: You could also use the [singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton) to specify what kind of environment it is when you start the application. Then you wouldn't need a DJ at all.

Comment: @Flimtix Would you mind to provide some implementation details? I'd really like to go with your approach, but don't know how to use Singleton pattern for this.. 

Comment: You may want to inject _IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment_ instead of _IWebHostEnvironment_:

`@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment _env;`

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#read-the-environment-in-a-blazor-webassembly-app) is what Microsoft documentation suggests for Blazor WASM -

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment Env
```

Then -

```
if (Env.IsDevelopment())
{
//Your Dev Environment specific code        
}
```