# Blazor Server, how to load file if in development

Tags: c#, .net, server, blazor, settings

Im on Blazor Server .Net6

How can I load a specific type of file/setting when the app meet this 2 conditions:

1. ** Development**  the app is still in development.
2. ** Production** the app is published.

During the Development stage i will connect to testing data and settings but after the app is published i will point other data.

```
        string = "";
        if (**Development**)
        {
            x = File.ReadAllText("wwwroot/settings/development.json");
        }
        else
        {
            x = File.ReadAllText("wwwroot/settings/production.json");
        }
```

Comment: Does this code not work? If not, how so?

Comment: What does "Develop and Deploy" mean? `IWebHostEnvironment` can tell you what environment the application thinks it's running in, but the names it provides don't match up with what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the `IWebHostEnvironment` interface to check the current mode.

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment _env;


@_currentMode
@code {
    string _currentMode;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            _currentMode = "dev mode";
        }else if (_env.IsProduction())
        {
            _currentMode = "production mode";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the `IWebHostEnvironment`:

`@inject IWebHostEnvironment Env` if in the page or

```
[Inject]
public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }
```

in the code behind.

Then you just use `Env.IsDevelopment()` which returns `bool`.

Check this similar question on Stack Overflow:
[How do I access env.IsDevelopment() from a Blazor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814637/how-do-i-access-env-isdevelopment-from-a-blazor-page)

Answer (score 1):

Use PreProcessor Directives.  Here's a simple example.

The advantage over using `Env.IsDevelopment()` is shown in the screenshot from Visual Studio. The appropriate code block for the current environment is highlighted.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="alert alert-primary">
@message
</div>

@code {
#if DEBUG
    private string message = "Development";
#else
    private string message = "Production";
#endif
}
```

[image]