How do you determine you are in development environment before calling AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter()
According to the documentation AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter() should only be called in the development environment.
The question is how do you determine you are in the development environment before the app has been created? The usual why to determine you are in the development environment is to call app.Environment.IsDevelopment(). The trouble is you have to call builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter() before app = builder.Build() but you can not call builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter() after the app is built.
It is interesting to note that when you create Blazor or ASP.Net core project they both simply call builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter() without regard to the current environment.

For Blazor, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814637/how-do-i-access-env-isdevelopment-from-a-blazor-page

@StevePy I don't see how that post helps me. In that post they are getting IWebHostEnvironment after the app has been built. I need the info before the app is built.

Qiang's suggestion may work, otherwise you could consider using a pre-compiler flag guard to add it only on #if DEBUG or another suitable new "DEVELOPMENT" flag ensuring that your production builds never use that flag.  I.e. releases should only ever use the Release configuration with no DEBUG/DEVELOPMENT defined.

Modified as Tim suggested:
var enviroment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
if (enviroment != null && enviroment.Equals("development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
}

Actually "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" variable maybe not set. But generally it will be set to "Development" in visual studio.

Thank you @qiangfu, that works. I suggest improving the answer with if (enviroment != null && enviroment.Equals("development", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

The answer is:
builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
I'm a bit embarrased about the question. I don't know how I missed this until now.
